# Python Neo4j Driver write_transaction returning empty result

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, bolt

I am using Neo4j version 4.0.1, with python driver version 4.0 on python 3.7.2

My Problem is, that within a transaction, the result from database contains records, while it does not if returned to outside the transaction. In my opinion, with a normal MATCH() query it should not be a problem to issue a query and consume it out-of-transaction, if one does not mind the possibility of lost-updates occuring.

The following code produces a minimum example.

```
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=(user, password), encrypted=False)

def get_all_foo_tx(tx):
    result = tx.run("MATCH(n:Foo) RETURN n.id")
    # result can be iterated over here
    # for record in result: 
    #     print(record)  
    return result

def get_all_foo():
    session = driver.session()
    db_result = session.write_transaction(get_all_foo_tx)
    # result is empty here
    # for record in result: 
    #     print(record)
```

My question is now: Is this expected behaviour?

With the previous Neo4j driver version, the code schematically outlined above worked, while it does not with the newest driver version.
I have taken a look at the "Breaking Changes" section of the documentation, and to me was nothing that could explain the change in behaviour.

Is consuming results outside the transaction a "bad practice"?

Notes: The code I'm actually executing is way more complicated than this, this is a minimum example.
The behaviour is consistent over a range of queries, where the result contains multiple records.
I have a property named id, which is separate from the internal Neo4j id; this is confusing on first sight.

Comment: Yes, consuming results outside the transaction is a bad practice. It's in the neo4j driver documentation here : https://neo4j.com/docs/driver-manual/current/session-api/configuration/#driver-simple-transaction-fn

"Any query results obtained within a transaction function should be consumed within that function, as connection-bound resources cannot be managed correctly when out of scope. To that end, transaction functions can return values but these should be derived values rather than raw results."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe your problem is that you are using `session.write_transaction`, but you want to only read the data from Neo4j. `write_transaction` method is designed for write queries where you include **CREATE**, **MERGE**, or **SET** in cypher. Try to use:

```
session = driver.session()
db_result = session.run(get_all_foo_tx)
// Just dont forget to close the session
session.close()
```

Hopefully, this will help.

Comment: So write_transaction is only intended for use in db-changing queries, but not in reading ones?
Thanks, I did not know that

Comment: No, write_transaction is not only intended for use in db-changing queries. Transaction functions can be called as either read or write operations. This choice will route the transaction to an appropriate server within a clustered environment. If you are operating in a single instance environment, this routing has no impact.